# Order by a function in a pageable Specification

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to have a user selection paginated with a search and a order by a custom function (levenshtein function).

The order by function allow me to display in first position the users with the firstname starting by the search characters, and then after, the user that have the search characters at any place into their firstname.

What I tryed :

- Use `@Formula` but we can not use variable into it to add the search parameter to the formula (exemple : "levenshtein('firstname', search-input)")
- Use of `query.orderBy` into a Specification but I get the error `PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`
- Use of a class `OrderBySqlFormula` for hibernate but I dont find where I can pass the object to the Specification
- Use of `JpaSort.unsafe` but I get error `[ERROR] No property ... found for type 'MyEntity'`

Did anyone have any idea to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance,
BrandonFL

Comment: Have you tried using `@Query` annotation to write the query yourself (possibly with `nativeQuery=true`)? Also, the `JpaSort.unsafe` option should work, but it's likely you've used a non-existing column there, if you fix that, it should work (but make sure to sanitize the input beforehand).

Comment: Hey @ŠimonKocúrek and thanks for your answer. The problem with `@Query` is that I can not use Specification and pageable requests :/

Comment: Can you recheck the `JpaSort.unsafe` in that case? Keep in mind that strings should be wrapped using `'` and column names are wrapped using `"`. Maybe the input string contains unescaped `"` characters and therefore Postgres thinks it's a column.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek I tested with `JpaSort.unsafe` but I get the error `[ERROR] No property ... found for type 'MyEntity'`. After some research, I have found this issue : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1946

I am not the only one that have this issue and `JpaSort.unsafe`  seems to do not work